# Reliable tote taking iOS app

Tags: ios, note-taking, iphone-app, ipad-app

Recently my Evernote yerly subscription ended and I have decided not to buy another year, because I would rather pay once (doesn't have to be free, but a one time purchase, not subscription based, I would pay up to 10-50$ for a good app) for an app like that and use my own backup methods (e.g. Dropbox).

iCloud synchronization would be preferred. It should be able to send the note via any app that supports it in PDF format.

So can someone recommend me a reliable note takeing app for iOS (iPhone and iPad, preferably Mac one as well but doesn't have to be)?

Comment: I guess that would have to free then (add 'gratis' tag)? What features do you need (what data types, synchronisation, search options, im/export ...)? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: I did, and no it doesn't have to be free, just a one time purchase fee, not subscription based.